# Insert html elements dynamically into a template of jsp file

Tags: html, jsp, templates

I want to insert some html elements dynamically into a template of jsp file.

I know I can do this by using a code snippet of javascript, but I wonder is there better ways?

Here my example:

myTemplate.jsp

```
......
<div id="content"></div>
.....
```

myPage.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="myTemplate.jsp"></jsp:include>

//This the line which I'm searching if there is.
setContent into the div with id "content"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible with JSP. Consider migrating from JSP to [Facelets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets004.htm). It's a XHTML based view technology. Then you'll be able to achieve the desired functionality with `<ui:insert>` and `<ui:define>`.

`/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`/WEB-INF/template.xhtml`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ui:insert name="content" />
    </body>
</html>
```

`/page.xhtml`

```html
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:define name="title">Page title</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Calling `/page.xhtml` in webbrowser will end up as

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
    <head>
        <title>Page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another advantage of Facelets is the builtin support for [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info), a component based MVC framework.

Answer (score 1):

Well, whatever framework you will use, that will be translated to some Browser Component[javascript/flash/applet] and some Server Side component[Servlet/Filter], if you want to modify content dynamically, **without refreshing the page**.
From that perspective plain JavaScript/Servlet combination is fine.
But for manageability perspective, use any java framework which has Ajax support. **JSF2, JSF with RichFaces, GWT** etc. to name a few.